# How to change the Value of a variable globally

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $var = "01-01-10";
    function checkkkdate($n)
    {
        global $var;   
        $var = $n;         
    } 
    echo  $var;
?>
```

The output should be what i send in function call
but it is giving output = 01-01-10
Please help

Comment: read manual : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: i think using `global` is very bad idea

Answer (score 3):

You didn't call your function. Call it before echoing value:

```
checkkkdate();
echo $var;
```

Comment: actually this is a demo function ..
in original i am giving value from outside this page, by calling function checkkkdate($n) and $var =$n
so i can't call the same function again :(

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call the function.

```
checkkkdate();
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 3):

Call to the function that changes the global variable is missing.

You need:

```
checkkkdate();    
echo $var;
```